# How to store data in Isolated Storage in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an app for windows phone 7.
I am using data which is coming from the web service which i want to save in isolated storage so that next time when the data is viewed it shows the data even when offline.

My cs file is:

```
public about()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    KejriwalService.aapSoapClient myclient = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
    myclient.getarvindAboutCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindAboutCompletedEventArgs>(myclient_getarvindAboutCompleted);
    myclient.getarvindAboutAsync();        
}

void myclient_getarvindAboutCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindAboutCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = e.Result;

    XElement xml = XElement.Parse(data);

    aboutview.Text = xml.Elements("UserDetails").Elements("about_details").First().Value;
}
```

Comment: Try to use sqlite that support windows phone. you can save your xml data into isolatedstorage but every time you need to parse data. that is a complex operation. So try to use a sqlite. once parse data and save data in a tabular structure.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to store data is to store them in the IsolatedStorageSettings. You can make a property for this purpose:

```
        string PropertyName
        {
            get
            {
                var settings = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
                if (settings.Contains("valueKeyName"))
                    return (string)settings["valueKeyName"];
                else
                    return null;
            }
            set
            {
                var settings = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
                if (settings.Contains("valueKeyName"))
                    settings["valueKeyName"] = value;
                else
                    settings.Add("valueKeyName", value);
            }
        }
```

IsolatedStorageSettings store pairs key-value in the dictionary. You should just choose key name of your storing value and name of the property.

Comment: what should i replace for valuekeyname.

Comment: Whatever you want. It's just a string key, that points to your value.

Comment: It can be for example "ParsedXmlTextForAboutViewKey" (it's not necessary to include "...Key" into it).

Comment: As Pradeep Kesharwani said in his comment, it must be the same throughout this application

Answer (score 0):

with the help ofIsolatedStorageSettings you could save your data in the form of key value paire like this:

```
 var Iso_settings = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;   
if (!Iso_settings.Contains("yourDataKey"))
    {
      Iso_settings.Add("yourDataKey", yourDataValue);
      Iso_settings.Save()//This will save your data in isolated storage.
    }
```

Comment: Iso_settings.Save(); // it's not necessary

Comment: It's necessary, if you want to save data immediately and then read immediately. But if you will read them only on another launch of your application, it's not, because IsolatedStorageSettings save when you close the application.

Comment: I can share another link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.95).aspx . There on calls of the Save method in the example. Also on those page: *On Silverlight for Windows Phone, IsolatedStorageSettings is not thread safe and throws an **IsolatedStorageException** when Save()()()() is called*

Comment: if, you are using your application and before exit your application have stuck with an exception that time your settings will not be saved.

Comment: So try to avoid the exceptions)) If your app stuck with an exception it's bad in any case. But I agree, in this case it'd be better if information was saved.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46805/discussion-between-pradeep-kesharwani-and-oleg-koposov)

Comment: @PradeepKesharwani can you please tell me what should i replace in yourdatakey and yourdatavalue

Comment: @use3156298yourdatekey is key that will be same throughout this program ,here you have to replace yourdatavalue

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for Sqlite if you don't want offline data and to store Data two best method is to use Isolated Storage and using linq so if you have only 1-2 data members and you have to change there values then you can use Isolated Storage otherwise go for linq if you have 2-3 columns and rows to store data in form of Tables.
Isolated storage is used like this:

```
try
{
    if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("email_id"))
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["email_id"] = emailid;
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["password"] = password;
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
    }
    else
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("email_id", emailid);
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("password", password);
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
}
```

For linq http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43025/A-LINQ-Tutorial-Mapping-Tables-to-Objects  go for the link.